# Why does PHP's urlencode use different URL encoding?

Tags: php, unicode, typo3, urlencode

The URL encoding of η is `%CE%B7`. But in PHP I get some strange symbols when I write `echo urldecode("%ce%b7");`

Instead, if I write `echo urlencode("η");` then I get `%26%23951%3B`. Why can't I use `%CE%B7`?

**Solution**

The Problem is that we use typo3. It some how does not use unicode for internal processing. As soon as we set `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['forceCharset'] = 'utf-8';` in typo3 the output of `echo urldecode("%ce%b7");` was correct.

For why `echo urlencode("η");` gives me `%26%23951%3B` see the answers of Joni.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urldecode("%ce%b7")` produces η *encoded in UTF-8*. If you are viewing the output with some other encoding you may see something else.

On the other hand, when you decode `%26%23951%3B` it's true that you don't obtain η; you obtain `&#951;` which is a HTML entity code for η. To decode entity codes use `html_entity_decode`:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#951;', false, 'UTF-8'); // prints η, encoded in UTF-8
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `echo html_entity_decode('&#951;', false, 'UTF-8');` does not print η. I have already `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` included. And the browser pretends to show it in unicode. Actually, `echo urldecode("%26%23951%3B");` prints η.

Comment: Actually, `echo urldecode("%26%23951%3B")` prints `&#951;`. If you happen to be viewing the result in a web browser, the browser shows this sequence of multiple characters as `η`. As to why the browser refuses to show a correctly encoded UTF-8 character despite the `Content-Type` header, it's hard to tell without seeing the page.

Comment: ok, now I see my problem. Thanks for pointing that out. But I still don't understand why `echo urldecode("%ce%b7");` is not displayed correctly.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the page. Maybe there's some non-UTF-8 text that makes the browser think the page is not encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo urldecode("%ce%b7"); // output : η
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.org/lgSmIjRV)